# What is the typical use for operator()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can overloading operator “function call” in C++ be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349867/how-can-overloading-operator-function-call-in-c-be-useful)

I see often where the parenthesis operator, `operator()`, is overloaded on a class or struct. I have never run into such a need myself, and wonder what is the typical use/need of this operator?

For instance, overloading `operator==` is accepted as returning true or false based on some equality made with the argument provided. This has a certain accepted and anticipated behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It's used a lot for the hashes, sets and algorithms component of STL to construct things called 'functors'.  For example:

```
using stl::map ;

map<string, string> myMap ;
```

but if you look at the specification for map it also includes a 'Compare' entry which defaults to less.  The Compare is the 'functor' you want map to use when comparing two keys.  It looks something like this:

```
template<class Key>
class less<Key> {
public:
  boolean operator()(const Key& a, const Key& b) { return a < b ;}
} ;
```

so what you have is:

```
 map<string, string, less<string> > myMap ;
```

and evertime you put something in the map or try to find something in the map it will use the less::operator() to do the comparisons.

You can use this to acchieve other effects such as when using 'sort' you can get sort to yield items in reverse order by using a different functor.

Comment: +1 for the example, that is a very helpful means of understanding the use, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator(), also known as the 'function call operator', to make an object behave like (and be usable as) a function.

These objects are often referred to as 'functors', but that shouldn't be confused with the same term from mathematics. I believe a more proper term is 'function object'.

Imagine you have a function that takes a callback. But suppose you need to store some state in that callback.

**[note: I haven't compiled this code, but you get the idea]**

```
void DoStuffAndCallBack(MyCallbackType Callback)
{
    ...
    Callback(args)
    ...
}
```

In C, or in 'C-with-classes'-style C++, you would pass a static callback function to this method, and store results in some global or class-static variable.

But in C++, the function could be written like so:

```
template<CallbackType>
void DoStuffAndCallBack(CallbackType Callback)
{
    ...
    Callback(args)
    ...
}
```

Now you can define a functor object that overloads `operator()` and pass an *instance* of that object to the function. That *instance* will get the callback, and any intermediate results you want to store can be stored in that *instance*.

In other words, it's a nice way to avoid globals (:

I'm sure there are other uses, but that's one good one, IMO.

Answer (score -2):

The canonical example is for a smart pointer class returning whether or not it is null, so you can do things like:

```
SmartPointer p = someOtherThing;
if (p) 
{ 
// do something 
}
```

In this case, the return type of the () operator should be bool, and the code will work as written. It creates a functor that allows the instance of the class to be called like a function.

Comment: Huh?  You didn't even use `operator()` here.

Comment: Testing an object with "if (obj)" does not use operator().

Comment: `operator()` is the function call operator. I think you're confusing it with the cast operator