# What does void Classname::operator()(){ .... } do?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, function-call-operator

Im working my way through some C++ code and came across the following

```
void Classname::operator()()
{   
    //other code here
}
```

I assume this has something to do with overloading the constructor, but can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349867/how-can-it-be-useful-to-overload-the-function-call-operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator()` is the function-call operator. It allows you to use a class instance like a function:

```
Classname instance;
instance(); //Will call the overload of operator() that takes no parameters.
```

This is useful for functors and various other C++ techniques. You can essentially pass a "function object". This is just an object that has an overload of `operator()`. So you pass it to a function template, who then calls it like it were a function. For example, if `Classname::operator()(int)` is defined:

```
std::vector<int> someIntegers;
//Fill in list.
Classname instance;
std::for_each(someIntegers.begin(), someIntegers.end(), instance);
```

This will call `instance`'s `operator()(int)` member for each integer in the list. You can have member variables in the `instance` object, so that `operator()(int)` can do whatever processing you require. This is more flexible than passing a raw function, since these member variables are non-global data.

Answer (score 3):

It makes your class an object called a "Functor" ... it's often used as a closure-type object in order to embed a state with the object, and then call the object as-if it were a function, but a function that has "state-ness" without the downside of globally accessible static variables like you would have with traditional C-functions that attempt to manage a "state" with internal static variables.

For instance, with

```
void Classname::operator()()
{   
    //other code here
}
```

An instance of `Classname` can be called like `class_name_instance()`, and will behave like a `void` function that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It's not overloading the constructor -- it's overloading the function-call operator. If you define this for a class, then you can invoke an instance of the class as if it were a function. Such an object is generally called a *functor*.

Answer (score 0):

That's the code to overload the operator '()' which basically allows you to use the class as a function with no parameters, you could also have something like:

```
SomeOtherClass Classname::operator ()(Argument1 a, Argument2 b, *[etc]*); and use it like:
Classname instance;
SomeOtherClass someother =  instance(arg1, arg2);
```

For more info on overloading you can check:
[Operators_in_C_and_C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)